# How can I get a token from a search in a whole file in vimscript?

Tags: regex, vim

Someone may have asked this before, but I can't find an answer on google...

1. The `search` function looks at the whole file in the buffer, but only returns the line number of the match.
2. The `matchstr` function can return a token, but only looks at one given string.

How can I realise the functionality that combines the two, and get the token from a search in a whole file? Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

#### Option A

You can use `searchpos()` to get line number and start column of the match, then use `getline()` and grab the match via `matchstr()`, using the column as the `{start}` argument (to properly handle multiple matches in a line).

#### Option B

Use `searchpos()` twice, the second time with the `ceW` argument to get the end of the match. Now you have two positions, and you can either set marks to both, then yank the text between them, or use `getline()` and `strpart()`.

#### Option C

My [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) has a `ingo#text#frompattern#Get( firstLine, lastLine, pattern, replacement, isOnlyFirstMatch, isUnique )` function that can extract such matches.

Comment: The ingo-library solution is superb. Here's a simple example to get you going: `let results = ingo#text#frompattern#Get(1, '$', 'quick \w\+', '', '', '')` -- run on a buffer of *the quick brown quick fox* would leave you with `results = ['brown', 'fox']`

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Vim (7.3.610 and above), you can (ab)use Vim's normal-mode search object "gn" to do this.

First, set the "last search" register to the pattern you want:

```
let @/='my pattern'
```

Next, go to the beginning of the file, and yank the next search hit:

```
normal! ggygn
```

Now, the search text is in register `@0`

If you want to use a different register, you can do that too:

```
normal! gg"aygn
```

Now it's in register `@a`

Note, all this will clobber the search and other registers, so it is polite to save and restore those registers. Something like:

```
function MyGetSearch(pattern)
  let oldpat=@/
  let @/=a:pattern
  let old_a=@a
  normal! gg"aygn
  let result=@a
  let @a=old_a
  let @/=oldpat
  return result
endfun
```

You can get even crazier with this, restoring cursor position and the like, but that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to convert the contents of the file to a string and then pass that as the `expr` argument of `matchstr()`:

```
  //get a list containing all lines in the file as items:
let lineList = readfile(<filename>)
  //join the lines into a single string using "\n" or your preferred line delimiter:
let fileString = join(lineList, "\n")
  //search fileString for your pattern:
let matchedText = matchstr(fileString, <pattern to match>)
```

[`readfile()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#readfile())
[`join()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#join())
[`matchstr()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#matchstr())

Bonus: If you want to do this with the current buffer instead of an arbitrary file, you can replace the call to `readfile()` with [`getline(1,'$')`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#getline()) to get a list containing all lines of the current buffer.